# SUM of a column with condition respect to fixed manual column value

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my source data where TIMESTAMP_WID refers YYYYMMDD

[image]

The output result I'm trying to achieve is as below,

[image]

The logic is as below,

**CUR_TIMESTAMP** refers,

```
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-2),'YYYYMMDD'))
```

The code I've tried so far is as below,

```
(SELECT 
OUTLET, 
SUM(SALES_VALUE), 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-2),'YYYYMMDD')) AS CUR_TIMESTAMP
FROM SOME_TABLE)
UNION
(SELECT 
OUTLET, 
SUM(SALES_VALUE), 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-3),'YYYYMMDD')) AS CUR_TIMESTAMP
FROM SOME_TABLE)
(SELECT 
OUTLET, 
SUM(SALES_VALUE), 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON'),-4),'YYYYMMDD')) AS CUR_TIMESTAMP
FROM SOME_TABLE)
```

In the above sql query, I'm able to populate same as my target, but, there is a very vital logic while calculating the **SUM(SALES_VALUE)**

When,

```
CUR_TIMESTAMP=20200101 
Then,
SUM(SALES_VALUE) will be calculated for 
TIMESTAMP_WID IN (20200101,20191201,20191101,20191001,20190901,20191001,20190901,20190801)
```

When,

```
CUR_TIMESTAMP=20201201 
Then,
SUM(SALES_VALUE) will be calculated for 
TIMESTAMP_WID IN (20191201,20191101,20191001,20190901,20191001,20190901,20190801,20190701)
```

When,

```
CUR_TIMESTAMP=20201101 
Then,
SUM(SALES_VALUE) will be calculated for 
TIMESTAMP_WID IN (20191101,20191001,20190901,20191001,20190901,20190801,20190701,20190601)
```

Anyone please guide me

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(sales_value) over (partition by outlet order by timestamp_wid) as running_sales_value
      from some_table st
     ) t
```

You can then add a `where` clause to filter the rows you want.  I think:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(sales_value) over (partition by outlet order by timestamp_wid) as running_sales_value
      from some_table st
     ) t
where timestamp_wid >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MON'), -4), 'YYYYMMDD')) and
      timestamp_wid < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MON'), -2), 'YYYYMMDD')) and
```